# Semver package.json version acceptable numbers

Tags: node.js, npm, semantic-versioning

I just have a quick question since I can't find a correct versioning formats.

For node.js modules package manager package.json

- 0.0.0 -> acceptable
- 10.0.0 -> acceptable
- 0.10.0 -> acceptable
- 0.0.10 -> acceptable?
- 0.0.01 -> not acceptable?

does versions accept any type of string? I doubt that since it needs to probably parse it as an integer or number type.

What is the acceptable version number format?

I will google it for you is also a very good answer right now ;)

Answer (score 0):

A normal version number MUST take the form X.Y.Z where X, Y, and Z are non-negative integers, and MUST NOT contain leading zeroes. X is the major version, Y is the minor version, and Z is the patch version. Each element MUST increase numerically. For instance: 1.9.0 -> 1.10.0 -> 1.11.0.